# how to attach the token to a graphql mutation request?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create this function to update details of user, before this function I have to login and get the token that I have to use in the next call.

I use this for init:

```
# Select your transport with a defined url endpoint
transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url=HOSTNAME_GRAPHQL, headers={'Authorization': 'token'})

# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)
```

and this funcion for call the mutation

```
def mutation_updateUser(client, id, username, firstName, lastName, access_token):

    # headers = {
    #     #"X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": access_token
    #     "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    # }
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer ' + access_token}

    query = gql(
        """
        mutation updateUser($input: UpdateUserInput!) {
          updateUser(input: $input) {
            id
            email
            username
            lastName
            firstName
            role
            avatar
          }
        }
    """
    )
    params = {
      "input": {
        "id": id,
        "username": username,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName
      }
    }
    request = client.execute(query, variable_values=params, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        return request.json()
    else:
        raise Exception("Query failed to run by returning code of {}. {}".format(request.status_code, query))
    #return result
```

when I run the program I got this error:
**

```
Si è verificata un'eccezione: TypeError
execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
  File "D:\Python project\API ReadyTGo\mutation_updateUser.py", line 36, in mutation_updateUser
    request = client.execute(query, variable_values=params, headers=headers)
```

**

**SOLVED THE PROBLEM!!**

I modify the function like this:

```
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport

from questions import HOSTNAME_GRAPHQL

def mutation_updateUser(id, username, firstName, lastName, access_token):

    # headers = {
    #     #"X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": access_token
    #     "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    # }
    #headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer ' + access_token}
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    _transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(url=HOSTNAME_GRAPHQL, use_json=True, headers=headers)
    client = Client(transport=_transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)

    query = gql(
        """
        mutation updateUser($input: UpdateUserInput!) {
          updateUser(input: $input) {
            id
            email
            username
            lastName
            firstName
            role
            avatar
          }
        }
    """
    )
    params = {
      "input": {
        "id": id,
        "username": username,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName
      }
    }
    request = client.execute(query, variable_values=params)
    return request.json()
```

I hope to help someone

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: when debug the program, the program stop at the line request = client.execute(query, variable_values=params, headers=headers)